# Makefile find all *.cpp and *.h files breaks in Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, shell, makefile

So the core of the problem is that I want to use my Makefile both under Linux and Windows.
When I use the common `CFILES := $(shell find $(SDIR) -name '*.cpp')` to find my `.cpp` files, the shell escape under Windows calls up an environment that ignores the fact that the MSYS64/bin is the first directory to look for programs in my PATH and uses the Windows intrinsic find command, that does something wildly different than the unix find program.

So I need to either

a) find a way that the make shell escape under windows does indeed use the "unixary" find that is found in my PATH

or

b) find a way to find all files without a shell escape ...

Comment: Try `CFILES := $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp)`. But this will not recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Sadly, that is something I need as the project would not be managable else

Comment: Can you add files to the current directory, or to another directory that is on the path?  You could have `myfind.bat` and `myfind` where the former calls `MSYS64\bin\find.exe` and the latter just calls `find`.

Comment: That might be an idea but so confusing, I guess for a project that I might upload  on github some day this will be just wierd.

Answer (score 1):

Try following and remove notdir function if you want directories as well.

YOUR_DIRECTORY = Your\Directory\Where\To\Find\FILES

YOUR_DIRECTORY_FILES = $(notdir $(shell dir /A-D /B  /S $(YOUR_DIRECTORY)*.cpp ))

## To Verify

${info Files $(YOUR_DIRECTORY_FILES)}

Comment: That sounded promising but for some reason the arguments to dir get interpreted as directories while entering the command in the terminal myself yields the correct outcome

Comment: just verify if shell it is pointing to is sh.exe (use ${info $(SHELL)), If not then in path variable move down directory of the current shell (that you get as output) and restart command prompt. 
This is tested as It worked for me recently